# How to insert date only in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I can insert an inactive timestamp interactively with `org-time-stamp-inactive` (`C-c C-!`), then pressing `Enter` when presented with the calendar. This inserts a value like `[2021-12-10 Fri]`.

I would like to know if this can be achieved programmatically with `org-time-stamp-inactive`. I tried `org-time-stamp-inactive '(16)` but this also inserts a time which I do not want. I can do `insert (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a]")` but this uses a different approach, and I would like to know if what I want can be achieved with org-time-stamp-inactive.

Comment: What you want to do is not clear from the above: are you hoping to call `org-time-stamp-inactive` and have it insert the current date in the current buffer *without* popping up the calendar and having to press `Enter`?  Or something else?

Comment: Correct. I would typically like to be able to bind some sort of function to a keypress that would insert the current date string (no time) into a document.

Comment: What's wrong with  what you suggested (other than some missing parens)?  This should work fine:  `(insert (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d]"))`.  You can wrap it in a command and bind it to a key too. You say this uses a "different approach": why does that matter? Ultimately, `org-time-stamp-inactive` does essentially the same insertion. FWIW, you can probably (i.e. I don't know for sure) contort `org-time-stamp-inactive` to do it, but it would be much more complicated.

Comment: Nothing wrong as such - it's just that I wanted to satisfy myself that it was / not possible to get the same effect with org-time-stamp-inactive, which seems to take various parameters giving different outputs, just (as far as I could see) not the one I want. The function doc hints at being able to do this: "If the user specifies a time like HH:MM or if this command is called with at least one prefix argument, the time stamp contains the date and the time. Otherwise, only the date is included."

Comment: OK - you twisted my arm :-) I looked at the code and edited the answer. TL;DR: no, it is not possible out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (in response to comment): No, it is not possible, but you got to look at the code to make sure. `org-time-stamp-inactive` is a thin wrapper around `org-time-stamp`. That in turn calls `org-insert-time-stamp`, which takes a `time` and a `with-hm` argument (among others - see the doc string of the function with `C-h f org-insert-time-stamp` for the details). If `with-hm` is `nil`, then no time is printed. But `org-time-stamp` (and therefore `org-time-stamp-inactive`) always calls `org-insert-time-stamp` with a non-nil `with-hm`, so the time is always inserted in that case. The best you can do is call the underlying function `org-insert-time-stamp` like so: `(org-insert-time-stamp (current-time) nil 'inactive)`.

I still think your simple suggested solution (elaborated a bit in the original answer below) is the best way to go about the problem.

---

[ORIGINAL ANSWER]

Org mode is plain text: things may appear differently, but all that is smoke and mirrors: you can `cat` an Org mode file in the terminal and see precisely what it contains. In particular, inactive time data are just strings of the form `[2021-12-11]`. So there is no penalty if you do it manually, instead of going through some Org mode interfaces: the end result is the same, so your manually inserted date is just as good as the one inserted by `org-time-stamp-inactive`.

So assuming that the simple solution you suggested is acceptable, here's filling in the details:

```el
(defun my/org-insert-current-time-as-inactive-time-stamp ()
   (interactive)
   (insert (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d]")))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c _") #'my/org-insert-current-time-as-inactive-time-stamp)
```

`C-c _` was undefined in the Org mode keymap in my case, but YMMV: choose something that is not used.